# Bind whole element to property in class

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a combobox in my XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="MyComboBox" />
```

I want to bind the whole object to a property in my view class:

```
public class MyView : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ComboBox MyComboBox;
    ...
}
```

I know how to bind individual properties of the combobox to a property in my view class but is there a way to bind the whole element?  I only need two properties so I could just bind the two properties separately but wanted to know if there is a way to do it in one shot.

Comment: You should not be binding entire UI elements in your view model. Bind only the values you need from these UI elements.

Comment: Say more about what you wish to accomplish.  I'm not sure it makes sense to bind a ComboBox to a Property... If the property is an object with its own properties, than you can set the DataContext of the ComboBox to that property value and then bind properties of the ComboBox (ItemsSource, etc) to the properties of that object.